# Drawing a clickable hexagon using GWT

Tags: gwt, canvas

What would be the best technique of drawing hexagon in GWT? I'd like it to be clickable, so would be great to have some click listener on this shape. Some canvas based solution I suppose?

Is there a built-in mechanism or I rather should use some 3rd party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For drawing 2D primitive shapes within GWT, check out GXT3. They added a nice Drawing API in version 3, based off of the techniques in Raphael. It uses fall-back mechanisms where it chooses the most performant, or most appropriate technology based on the browser being used. It even works for IE6, albeit with some minor display/animation differences.

It can also animate objects, and display SVG based data.
See the Logos examples within the Draw section of the demos, and try scaling the window.

[Sencha GXT Examples](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/examples/)

Comment: what about seting click listeners on such shapes?

Comment: Yes I believe they support the full-capabilities of their Component model, including drag-n-drop. They use the same draw API for their charts, which says a lot about the draw API's capabilities IMO. Cheers, Troy